# Nginx Error: unknown directive rewrite

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite, nginx, passenger

I have a rewrite in my nginx.conf:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

But return this error: **unknown directive "rewrite"**.

PS: I've installed nginx with passenger.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the output of nginx -V.  If you see the option --without-http_rewrite_module, then you probably didn't have the pcre development package installed when you build nginx, and so it disabled the rewrite module.  If that's the case, you'll need to install the pcre devel packages (how to do this depends on your distro) and rebuild nginx.

Comment: Yes, I have this line ):

I don't have much experience, you know any tutorial to recompile nginx with passenger?

Comment: I don't especially care for passenger, I would suggest keeping nginx separate from your application server.  It's designed to be a small, fast reverse proxy.  Setting up unicorn/thin/mongrel/whatever to run your ruby code and proxy_passing to it from nginx allows you to use the prebuilt package from your distro, which will include the rewrite module, and you'll be more likely to receive help in the irc channel without third party modules.

Comment: Ok, I will reinstall the Nginx and Passenger! Thx!

Comment: To install pcre devel packages on Ubuntu, issue: `apt-get install libpcre3-dev`